# Wrong output with a csv file

Tags: python, csv

The point of the program is to get a table with one line or with lines from the given range (by the line number). The function either copies the original data, or creates a new table view that works with the original data set (`copy_table = False`), so the changes made through this view will be observed in the original table as well.
This is my code:

```
import csv

def get_rows_by_number(file, start, stop, copy_table=False):
    if start >= stop:
        print('Wrong range')
    res = []
    csv.field_size_limit(1000000000)
    try:
        with open(file, mode='r') as f:
            read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
            for i in read:
                res.append(i)
    except IOError:
        print('This file does not exist')
    if copy_table:
        with open(file, mode='w', newline='') as f:
            write = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\r')
            for i in range(start, stop):
                print(res)
                write.writerow(res)
    else:
        with open(file, mode='w', newline='') as f:
            write = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\r')
            for i in range(start, stop):
                print(res)
                write.writerow(res)

get_rows_by_number(r'participants.csv', 1, 4, False)
```

And i guess something is wrong here as the output is just the whole table but not the lines from the given range.
Link to the [participants.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HWKLAf4oLV8ofovkh6Q_WuD_UHpu1IBZ/view?usp=sharing) file if needed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use

```
write.writerow(res[i])
```

instead

```
write.writerow(res)
```

Comment: Now it says File "C:\Users\Nika\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    get_rows_by_number(r'C:\Users\Nika\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\participants.csv', 1, 4, False)
  File "C:\Users\Nika\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 30, in get_rows_by_number
    print(res[i])
IndexError: list index out of range             :/

Comment: Tested my solution, it works for me. Are you sure that your file contains more lines than the value of the stop parameter?